# Is there a way to provide a filter to a workflow for a particular item searched by a user? EDITED

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

When you right click on a list item, workflows show up and you can select a workflow for that item.

Is there a way to provide a filter for a workflow for a user to search for a particular item such as a month column or last name column and run that workflow only on that?

EDIT: Yes I should clarify more. Apologies.
When you right click workflows and select a workflow by clicking on that workflow button, it usually goes the next page with a button to start.
I have seen along with that button start a field box or two.
What is it's major function and how do you do that?
It seems like it can be used as a filter or modify or update a field against that workflow.

Comment: Hi @Mike Should you elaborate more what do you need in filter for a workflow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own work flow initialization form and you can add text box for last name and date picker for month. At time of work flow start you can specify those fields value and you can use those field value in work flow.

Below is reference URL to create workflow initialization form.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-workflow-initiation-form-26879578-a62b-4fef-8b7e-9e4400afc94b

Comment: Is there a place you can point me to an example? Are the fields added through the info path workflow form and how do I tie that in? Sorry a little confused. Thank you again.

Comment: check my updated answer.